# DJANGO 1.1 dynamic url on static javascript

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x

### Context

I am adding a static JavaScript file to my **ModelForm** on this way.

**forms.py**

```python
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Media:
      js = ('some-javascript.js',)
```

### Problem

On this javascript I need send a GET request to a rest endpoint hosted on same application using jQuery, but i need the Server domain or a function to construct my url.

**some-javascript.js**,

```javascript
django.jQuery.get('{% url "validate_username" %}')
```

### expected behaviour

If I could create my url with django I could send the request without problems, Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use django template language inside your static javascript file.
You have two options to work around this.

Move your javascript code from your static file to your html template.
Like this.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.get('{% url "validate_username" %}')
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Else, set your url to the javascript window object and then use it inside your static javascript file.
Like this.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.my_url = '{% url "validate_username" %}';
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: But I do not use the template, I'm using ** forms.ModelForm **, there is some way using templates, to add all the fields of the modelForm?